# Не работает перехват СМС на телефон Meizu MX3

Tags: android, sms, broadcast-receiver

Стандартный код SMS-Receiver, опробованный на многих моделях Андроид, не работает на Meizu MX3 -  Flyme 3  - Android 4.4. Причина: `bundle = null`.

```
public class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null &&
                ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Не удается прочитать SMS. Bad bundle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

        //// TODO: 12.12.15 test
        if (pduArray == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Не удается прочитать SMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
        }
        String sms_from = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        //if (sms_from.equalsIgnoreCase("life:)")) {
            StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
              bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
            }
            String body = bodyText.toString();
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SmsService.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
            context.startService(mIntent);

            abortBroadcast();
        //}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Значит intent пустой, без extra записей

Comment: @Saidolim, понятно, но в чем причина этого?